# How to initialise a mapping of a structure inside a function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, mapping, struct

I am having a struct which is having a map and I want to update the map dynamically...

Code :

```
struct task {
        string description;
        status taskStatus;
        address assignedTo;
        uint deadline;
        mapping (address => bool) allocation;
    }
  

function setTask (string memory _desc , address[] calldata _copartner , uint _deadline) external  {
      
       
        TaskList.push(task({description : _desc , taskStatus : status.Set , assignedTo : msg.sender , deadline : block.timestamp + _deadline }));
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a struct element empty inside your structs array and then you can fill it with relative values in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Test {

    enum status { Set, Done }
    task[] TaskList;

    struct task {
        string description;
        status taskStatus;
        address assignedTo;
        uint deadline;
        mapping (address => bool) allocation;
    }
    

    function setTask (string memory _desc , address[] calldata _copartner , uint _deadline) external  {
        task storage t = TaskList.push();
        t.description = _desc;
        t.taskStatus = status.Set;
        t.assignedTo = msg.sender;
        t.deadline = block.timestamp + _deadline;
        t.allocation[msg.sender] = true;
    }
}
```